# Why did Kurama keep helping Naruto?

Tags: naruto

As I was browsing through an old [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4550/what-will-happen-to-the-tailed-beast-if-the-jinchuruki-is-killed), the answer shocked me. It seems that if Naruto were killed, Kurama would just revive. Then why did Kurama give Naruto some of its chakra when he was on the verge of death? For instance, when Naruto first summoned Gamabunta while falling to his potential death, Kurama gave him some chakra and helped him out. Wasn't Kurama's dream to break free from Naruto? What's the need of breaking the seal when he can just let Naruto die and he is free? He did push Naruto to the point of opening the gate when Naruto fought with Pain. Why not just sit tight and let Naruto die? Did I miss something? All this while I thought if the host dies so does the tailed beast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason might be because if the Jinchuuriki dies, the bijuu will indeed be set free. However, the bijuu will also "die" first. The bijuu will "die" first before reviving itself after some time. Where it revives might also be random, as seen in Isobu's case. Isobu, or more commonly known as the Sanbi, revived itself after its host, the 4th Mizukage died. It revived itself in a lake.

Now, Kyuubi might want to avoid this. There are three possible reasons for this.

1. Kyuubi had half of his chakra sealed in the 4th Hokage with Shiki fuuin. Because of this seal, even if the Kyuubi had revived itself, it would have revived with only what he had during the time he was sealed in Naruto.
2. Kyuubi dislikes the idea of having to die first. Kurama's nature is a bit prideful, so that fits.
3. The half of Kyuubi that was sealed in Naruto was the less sinister half, and Naruto had the power to attract people, so this half might have taken interest in Naruto ever since Naruto used his power to defeat Haku.

Answer (score 0):

Kurama is quite a prideful one and wanted to defeat the Jinchuriki and gain control instead of simply dying.
Jinchuriki were shunned and outdasted by people because of having a beast sealed in them, or needed an extremely strong person to keep the bijuu sealed in them and several Jinchurikis in the past couldn't control their emotions and the tailed beast broke free.

His hatred for humans was immense and he took great pride in belittling them. Naruto was quite impulsive, so kurama gave him his chakra to make his presence felt which would make naruto seek more and more.
In the encounter with orochimaru at the tenchi Bridge, kurama is shown belittling naruto, trying make him submit himself and seek his power.
Then in the progressive battles where naruto is emotionally broken it tries to takeover naruto through his hatred until finally it almost broke free in the battle with pain after naruto was hopelessly broken(thanks to the fourth hokage, the attempt failed).

So to sum up,Kurama's sense of identity was strong, for him naruto was just a cage that held him. Almost like HE WAS NARUTO, not some enslaved creature that donated power as and when asked.  Like it looks, his identity was very strong and being sealed didn't stop him from being what he is, THE NINE TAILS, THE MOST POWERFUL BIJUU.He showed his ominous presence and didn't want some puny human to defeat him in any form.